# rails select, with restricted query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Currently I am trying to restrict the information feed into an option select field to only display the criteria I have selected. With the code below this seems to be working

```
= select("schedule", :selected_players, User.where(:team_id => current_user[:team_id]) { |p| [full_name(p), p.id] }, {:include_blank => 'None', :prompt => 'Add Players to Lineup'}, :multiple => "multiple")
```

The issue is that this code is displaying an array field type i.e #<User:0xa559830>.

How do I get it to display the actual users name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest rewriting the code with greater separation and clarity instead of trying to fit it all in one line. Model methods that generate SQL should never be called from views.

In the controller:

```
@players = User.where(:team_id => current_user[:team_id]).all
```

In the view:

```
= select :schedule, :selected_players, @players.map {|p| [full_name(p), p.id] }, {:include_blank => true}...
```

I think the original error in your code appears to be that you were calling a block after the `where` method without an iterator (`each`).

Comment: this code now gives me `undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: There could be any number of reasons for that. Are other instance variables from the controller available and passed correctly?

Comment: Hi Andrew, there is 2 other instance variables within that action in my controller which were working prior to adding this one in